# Bootstrap popover repeats an action/ event twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Why Bootstrap's popover **repeats an action twice**? For instance, I want to **submit** a form inside the popover's `data-content` via `ajax`. It repeats all the form data **twice** and the posts form **twice**.

Any idea what I can do about it?

jquery + bootstrap,

```
$('.bootstrap-popover-method').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html:true,
    content: function () {
        var p = $(this);
        var data = $('#popover-content').html();
        $('#popover-content').remove();
        p.attr("data-content", data);
        p.popover('show');
    }
});

$('.bootstrap-popover-method').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    // do something…
    console.log(this); // I get twice of the button element <button class="btn btn-default bootstrap-popover-method"...>
    console.log($(".btn-submit").length); // I get twice of '1'.

    $(".link").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr("href")); // I get once of 'test.html'.
        return false;
    });

    $(".btn-submit").click(function(){

        console.log($(this).closest("form").attr("action")); // I get twice of '1.php'

        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        console.log(form.serialize()); // I get twice of 'username=hello+world!'

        $.ajax({ // it posts twice to 'POST https://localhost/test/2014/css/bootstrap/1.php'

            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
          });

        return false;
    });


});
```

bootsrap + html,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default bootstrap-popover-method" data-title="body" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
  Popover on bottom
</button>

<div id="popover-content">
    <a href='test.html' class="link">hello</a> 
    <form action="1.php" class="myform">
       <input type="text" name="username" value="hello world!"/>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-submit"/> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: any issue explain me!!

Comment: !! is this is a form button

Answer (score 2):

This happens because popover.content checks if the tooltip is empty or not.

A simple fix would be to add a title attribute to popover.

```
$('.bootstrap-popover-method').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html:true,
    title: "New Title",
    content: function () {
        var p = $(this);
        var data = $('#popover-content').html();
        $('#popover-content').remove();
        p.attr("data-content", data);
        p.popover('show');
    }
});
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12563#issuecomment-56813015

Comment: it took 4 hours to resolve this simple issue, thanks buddy it helps

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old post, but i'm gonna leave here my work around.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.5.

So the buggy behavior is that on every execution of "popover('show')", Bootstrap calls the rendering function twice, and **only the second call** is the one that actually renders the popup.

My fix is to return a short html string for the first call, and for the second call i let run the whole rendering function:

```
jQuery('.bootstrap-popover-method').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: function(){//This is our rendering function for the popup's content
        var __G_bs_popover_shown= jQuery.data(jQuery('body')[0], '__G_bs_popover_shown');

        //Create a global variable, attached to the body element, to keep track of the repeating calls.
        __G_bs_popover_shown= (typeof __G_bs_popover_shown == 'undefined') ? 1 : (__G_bs_popover_shown + 1) % 2;
        //Update the global var
        jQuery.data(jQuery('body')[0], '__G_bs_popover_shown', __G_bs_popover_shown);
        //return a short string on every first call (this will not be rendered, anyway)
        if(__G_bs_popover_shown == 1) return '<div>BLANK</div>';//==>this should not be an empty string!

        //PLACE YOUR CODE HERE, E.G. AJAX CALLS, ETC..
        //DON'T FORGET TO RETURN THE HTML FOR THE POPUP'S CONTENT!
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to prevent the default event of the submit button

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).closest("form").attr("action")); // I get twice of '1.php'

    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    console.log(form.serialize()); // I get twice of 'username=hello+world!'

    $.ajax({ // it posts twice to 'POST https://localhost/test/2014/css/bootstrap/1.php'

        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.bootstrap-popover-method').off('shown.bs.popover')
                                      .on('shown.bs.popover', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
```

// unbind your submit button click

```
$(".btn-submit").off('click').on('click',function(){

        console.log($(this).closest("form").attr("action")); // I get twice of '1.php'

        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        console.log(form.serialize()); // I get twice of 'username=hello+world!'

        $.ajax({ // it posts twice to 'POST https://localhost/test/2014/css/bootstrap/1.php'

            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
          });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more detail? As it stands, this answer is fairly useless...

Comment: LoL. One of the worst SO response NA.

Comment: Now, I'm updating as I understand this problem. Hope it works for you guys.