# How to disable multiple ajax call in a bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-popover

I have implemented a popover. Whenever you click on an element I will make an AJAX request. Unfortunately there are two AJAX calls being sent. How do I prevent this? I only want to make a single AJAX call.

```js
$(".btn-course-user").popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'manual',
  viewport: '',
  template: '',
  placement: 'bottom',
  content: function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'lorem/ipsum/',
      dataType: 'html',
      async: false
    }).responseText;
  }
}).click(function(e) {
  $(this).popover('toggle');
});
```

Whenever I click on the element with class selector `.btn-course-user` it sends two AJAX requests. Can someone help me to prevent it. I want to send a single request.

Comment: There's two general approaches to this. 1) Perform the AJAX request first and then populate the content of the popovers from the returned data 2) Use a better tooltip library which has AJAX functionality built in to it. I would strongly suggest the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was i have not added title property for the popover.

[For more clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707400/bootstrap-popover-repeats-an-action-event-twice)

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but consider running the request before the popover, as it might be referencing `content` multiple times during instantiation, causing the ajax to fire more than once:

```
$(".btn-course-user").click( e => {
  // maybe show a loading message....
  let thisObj = $(this) ;
  $.ajax({
   url: 'lorem/ipsum/',
   dataType: 'html'
  }).done(function(ajaxContent) {
   thisObj.popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        viewport: '',
        template: '',
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: ajaxContent
    }).off('click').click(function (e) {
        $(this).popover('toggle');
    });
  });
});
```